# ¿Como compartir un archivo por Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

con este código puedo compartir archivos (en mi caso un zip) con otras aplicaciones.
Con mi teléfono y el emulador no hay problema, pero al probarlo con una tablet y otro dispositivo me da error. Es decir solo funciona en ciertos dispositivos. Mi pregunta es ¿Hay algun otro modo con el que realizar la misma tarea pero sin recibir estos errores?

```
var uri = Uri.fromFile(File("mi ruta")


var sendIntent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
sendIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
sendIntent.type = "application/*"


startActivity(ctx, Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Compartir con:"), null)//Es aquí donde me lanza el error
```

**LogCat:**

```
> 2020-04-13 22:13:09.918 16753-17335/com.toni.storyplanner
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: compartir_copia_de_seguridad
> Process: com.toni.storyplanner, PID: 16753
> android.os.FileUriExposedException:
> file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.toni.storyplanner/files/Documents/CopiaDeSeguridad/StoryPlanner.zip
> exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri() at
> android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1960) at
> android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2356) at
> android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:945) at
> android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10604) at
> android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10610) at
> android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10589) at
> android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1618)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4621) at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4579) at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4940) at
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:251)
> at
> seguridad.Compartir_copia_de_seguridadKt.compartir_copia_de_seguridad(compartir_copia_de_seguridad.kt:32)
> at
> seguridad.Copia_de_seguridadKt$copia_de_seguridad$tread3$1.run(copia_de_seguridad.kt:85) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Como es la ruta? el archivo existe? Que error se muestra en el LogCat?, acostumbra agregar esa informaciòn en tus preguntas. saludos.

Comment: El LogCat lo dejo en la publicación, y la ruta del archivo seria la siguente: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.toni.storyplanner/files/Documents/CopiaDeSeguridad/StoryPlanner.zip **El archivo si existe se guarda sin problemas**. Gracias por tu comentario, un saludo.

Comment: Creo que deberías utilizar FileProvider, Android recomienda utilizar FileProvider que es una subclase de Contentprovider. Enlace -> https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/FileProvider En una búsqueda por GitHub encontré un ejemplo que te puede ayudar
Ejemplo -> https://github.com/drivy/blog-android-fileprovider Espero te ayude :)